# How to disable logging of HTTP requests in VS Code

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, visual-studio-code

How can I disable or hide logging of HTTP requests.  When I run my app, the `Debug Console` is full of info logs, like these:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action MyApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyApp) in 128.658ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action MyApp.Controllers.HomeController.Index (MyApp) in 128.658ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 356.7146ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 356.7146ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/css/site.css
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#logging-providers Clear logging providers and add none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [log level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#log-level-1) for your program, and if you are running your program in local environment, you'd better to modify `appsettings.Development.json` rather than `appsettings.json`.

According to your snippet, I think modify the log level to be warning can achieve your goal. Here's my configuration and the test result before and after adding the configuration. And if you wanna only hide those info which contains http request, you can also use `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning"` instead of `"Microsoft": "Warning"`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to see it worked for you, thanks for your reply sir :）